# SWR MUTATION AXIOS NEXT JS - Unhandled Runtime Error AxiosError: Request failed with status code

Tags: next.js, axios, swr

I have a error when i use swr mutation axios like this.
the response api found but show this modal error of next js.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvirO.png)

My code
fetch.ts

```js
export const loginFetch = async (
    url,
    { arg }
) => {
     try {
// with fetch no problem but with axios show this modal next error
    const data = await BASE_URL.post<APIAuthLogin>(url, arg);
  
    return data;
}
}
```

form.tsx:

```js
  const { trigger, error } = useMutation("/auth/login", loginFetch);

    async function onLogin(datos: AuthLogin) {
        await trigger(datos);
    }
```